# Adding a new database to an existing sql cluster

Tags: sql-server, clustering

I got a requirement in my company, where a third party application requires just one database. The Application owner told me that he is OK with the database being created in an existing SQL Server instance on a cluster.  I have two questions regarding this

1) Can I use the existing drives (Data,log) drives, create a new database and map the mdf and ldf to the existing mountpoints?

2) Do I need to create another MSDTC drive for this application?

Please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The application is for a secure print project. It allows for print roaming and authentication on all the campuses without having to setup multiple printer  drivers on user endpoints. This is what the project is about. I will findout from the application owner if they require msdtc for the application.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use the existing drives (Data,log) drives, create a new database and map the mdf and ldf to the existing mountpoints?

Yes you can use the existing drives for new database. You would need a new set of shared drives if you are installing new SQL Server clustered instance.

> Do I need to create another MSDTC drive for this application?

Not necessarily, a single MSDTC can work for multiple instances. But if you want to know what all queries need MSDTC I would direct you to Cindy Gross Blog [Do I Need MSDTC for SQL Server Cluster](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cindygross/2010/10/18/do-i-need-dtc-for-my-sql-server/). Quoting

> If your application calls DTC directly or if you use a feature in SQL Server that calls DTC, then you need DTC to be available. Some examples of how SQL Server uses DTC: linked servers, OPENROWSET, OPENQUERY, OPENDATASOURCE, remote procedure calls, BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION, updatable subscriptions for transactional replication (immediate and queued updating are now deprecated). You can choose to enlist in a DTC transaction from CLR, SSIS, and DTS. SQL Server does not support using DTC with some features such as database mirroring.

Comment: Thanks for replying back. Also, should I create a secondary database in the failover node with the same name or is it not necessary? Kindly clarify

Comment: What do you mean by secondary database ?. Are you talking about AOAG ?

Comment: No, Its a SQL cluster not an AAG group. So if they want me to create a database, should I be creating it on the node which is Active? and then map the database files to a shared disk?

Comment: Since storage is shared in cluster and both nodes can take ownership of it it does not really matter from where you create it so when you create database it will reside on shared disk in data file. You can login to any node connect to DB instance by providing virtual SQL Server name and create database. Normally I prefer from active node.